# What are the permission needed for a ServicePrincipal to call getObjectsByObjectIds?

Tags: c#, azure-ad-graph-api

What are the permission needed for an Service Principal to call AD graph API: Get Objects By Object Ids:

POST https://graph.windows.net/{tenantID}/getObjectsByObjectIds?api-version=1.6

I set up an App with

Application Permission: Read directory data.

Delegated Permission:

Read Directory data
Read and write directory data
Read all users full profile
Sign in and read user profile.

But I am receiving Forbidden ( status code 403) while making the API call:

[image]

Also i got access token through this code:

string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + "microsoft.com";

```
        AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

        ClientCredential cr = new ClientCredential("Appid", "Cred");
        string OfficeUrl = "https://graph.windows.net";
        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = ac.AcquireTokenAsync(OfficeUrl, cr).Result;
        string token = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
        // string token = this.SetAuthorizationToken();           
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is correct permissions of Read directory data (Directory.Read.All) is required for this API. Please make sure to press the "Grant Permissions" button after adding the required permissions for the Graph API because this permission requires admin consent.[image]

Comment: Yes the app is granted permission, Do I need to give any permission for Microsoft graph API for this?

Comment: You need to provide access to "Windows Azure Active Directory" for Azure AD Graph API.  However, Microsoft recommends to use Microsoft Graph over Azure AD Graph. If you are using Microsoft Graph then you need to provide permissions to "Microsoft Graph".

Comment: Have you tried using Azure AD Graph Explorer to do the same ?

Comment: Also, If you are getting the access token through C# code then why trying to go for POST operation instead of using the GetObjectsByObjectIdsAsync method of ActiveDirectoryClient ?  Also, in your code authority should be like  = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + Tenant Name which could be "abc.onmicrosoft.com" and not only "microsoft.com"

Comment: I moved to Microsoft Graph and the issue got resolved.